# Verify Jackon JsonAnySetter is called Junit

Tags: java, junit, java-8, jackson, mockito

I have a POJO and I am using Jackson to deserialize it into the POJO.I want to log key value attributes which I'm not aware of. For this I use JsonAnySetter in the following manner:

```
@Value
@Slf4j
@Builder
public class Book {
  private String titleId;
  private String bookName;
  private List<String> authors;

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void ignored(String key, Object value) {
        log.warn("Received a key which hasn't been mapped. Key: {}, Value: {}", key, value);
    }
}
```

Now to test this in my Junit how do I verify that the method ignored is called?

```
@Test
public void given_unknown_key_ensure_it_is_logged() {
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   String test = "{\"randomField\": \"test\"}";
   Book book = objectMapper.readValue(test, Book.class);
  ArgumentCaptor<Book> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Book.class);
   verify(book, times(1)).ignored("randomField", "test");
}
```

I need to use the actual Book object, but that has to be mocked as well, so not sure how I should proceed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mock object of the `Log` object and set it in the `Book` class.

This assumes that the Log object is static,
which seems reasonable.

Comment: are you suggesting to check if log.warn has been called? But should't I ensure that ignored method is called?

Comment: Use verify to check if the log was called.

Comment: Hmm... How do I ensure it is the log method in ignored only and not some other method.

Comment: also that would mean using Power mockito